# Can't save Object from API as new contact in lightning component

Tags: lightning, contact, sobject, create

I need to save the data filled through API as a new Contact but i receive the follow msg when i press the "save" button:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:cars$controller$clickSave [action is not defined] Failing descriptor: {c:cars$controller$clickSave}

Here is my code, please help me

**cars.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="carsController">

    <aura:attribute name="carId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="carFound" type="Boolean"  default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="car" type="Object" />
    
    
    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <lightning:layout class="slds-page-header slds-page-header--object-home">
        <lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:icon iconName="standard:expense" alternativeText="My Cars"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
            <div class="page-section page-header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading--label">Cars</h1>
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">My Cars</h2>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">
        
    <div aria-labelledby="newcarsform">
        <!-- BOXED AREA -->
        <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--small">
        <legend id="newcontactform" class="slds-text-heading--small 
          slds-p-vertical--medium">
          Add car
        </legend>
  
        <form class="slds-form--stacked">
            <lightning:input aura:id="enter-search" name="enter-search" label="Type a number to search" type="search" value="{!v.carId}"/>
            <lightning:button label="Search" 
                              class="slds-m-top--medium"
                              variant="brand"
                              onclick="{!c.clickSearch}"/>
            
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.carFound}">
                <lightning:input aura:id="carform" label="Name"
                                 name="carname"
                                 value="{!v.car.name}"
                                 required="true"/> 
                <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="carform" label="Height"
                                 name="caramount"
                                 min="1"
                                 step="1"
                                 value="{!v.car.height}"
                                 messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Enter car height"/>
                <lightning:input aura:id="carform" label="Color"
                                 name="carform"
                                 value="{!v.car.color}"
                                 placeholder="Color"/>
                <lightning:input aura:id="carform" label="Wheels"
                                 name="carwheel"
                                 value="{!v.car.wheel}"/>
                <lightning:input aura:id="carform" label="Car lights"  
                                 name="carlights"
                                 value="{!v.car.lights}"/>
                <lightning:input aura:id="carform" label="Brand"
                                 name="carbrand"
                                 value="{!v.car.brand}"
                                 required="true"/> 
                <lightning:input aura:id="contactform" label="Model"
                                 name="carmodel"
                                 value="{!v.car.model}"
                                 required="true"/> 
                <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="carform" label="Car number"
                                 name="carnumber"
                                 value="{!v.car.Number}"
                                 required="true"/> 
                <lightning:button label="Guardar" 
                                  class="slds-m-top--medium"
                                  variant="brand"
                                  onclick="{!c.clickSave}"/>
            </aura:if>
                
        </form>
  
      </fieldset>
    </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

**carsController.js**

```
({
    clickSearch: function(component, event, helper) {     
        var id = component.get("v.carId");
        helper.getResponse(component, id);
        console.log(component, event, helper);
    },
    clickSave: function(component, event, helper) {
        var validContact = component.find('carform').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
            // Displays error messages for invalid fields
            inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
        }, true);
        // If we pass error checking, do some real work
        if(validCar){
            // Create the new Car
            var car = component.get("v.car");
            console.log("Create Car: " + JSON.stringify(character));
            helper.createCar(component, character);
        }
    }
})
```

**carsHelper.js**

```
({
    getResponse: function(component, id) {
        // create a server side action.       
        var action = component.get("c.getCalloutResponseContents");
        // set the url parameter for getCalloutResponseContents method (to use as endPoint) 
        action.setParams({
            "url": 'https://api.cars/models/'

        });
        console.log("trying connection");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                // set the response(return Map<String,object>) to response attribute.   
                var response = response.getReturnValue();
                if(response) {
                    component.set("v.characterFound", true);
                    component.set("v.character", response);

                }
                console.log("Connection established");
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    createCar: function(component, con) {
        console.log('inside helper');
        var con = component.get("v.car")
        var theCars = component.get("c.saveCar");
        console.log('after method called');
        //var newCar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(car));
        theCars.setParams({
            "jsonCharacter": JSON.stringify(car)
            //component.get("v.cars")
        });
        console.log('im here');
        theCars.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('pass callback');
            if (component.IsValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log('im inside if');
                var car = component.get("v.car");
                cars.push(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.car", response.getReturnValue());
                alert('Car inserted correctly');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

        //theContacts.push(newCar);
        //component.set("v.cars", theCars);
    }
})
```

**carsController.apxc**

```
public class carsController {
    // Pass in the endpoint to be used using the string url
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Character getCalloutResponseContents(String url) {
 
        // Instantiate a new http object
        Http h = new Http();
 
        // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
 
        // Send the request, and return a response
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        System.debug('response:--> ' + res.getBody());
        
        // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
        if(String.isBlank(res.getBody())) {
            return null;
        }
        
        Car carFound = (Car) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), Car.class);
        system.debug('car-->' + carFound);
    
        return carFound;
        
    }
    
    public class Car {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String name;
        @AuraEnabled
    public String height;
        @AuraEnabled
    public String color;
        @AuraEnabled
    public String wheel;
        @AuraEnabled
    public String lights;
        @AuraEnabled
    public String brand;
        @AuraEnabled
    public String model; 
        @AuraEnabled
    public String number;

    }
    
        @AuraEnabled
    public static void saveCar(String jsonCar) {
        Car c = (car) Json.deserialize(jsonCharacter, Car.class);
        Car car = new Car(FirstName = car.name,
                                      Height__c = car.height,
                                      Gender__c = car.wheel,
                                      Lights__c = car.lights,
                                      Brand__c = car.brand,
                                      Model__c = car.model,
                                      CarNumber__c = car.Number);

        insert car;     
    }
}
```

**carsApp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:cars/>
</aura:application>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: just edited variables for security, please dont roll back

Comment: I've rolled back changes to this question because the code that was problematic and answered by Sanket was removed. Please do not remove content after the community has engaged - you are welcome to _add_ information, however. We want this question and answer to provide value to other readers too.

Answer (score 1):

Your helper method named **createContact** is causing the issue.

```
    createContact: function(component, contact) {
        //valling the method and storing it in variable called theContacts 
        var theContacts = component.get("c.saveContact");
        // you should use theContacts.setParams instead of action.setParams
        action.setParams({
            "Contact": contact
            //component.get("v.contacts")
        });
        // you should use theContacts.setCallback instead of action.setCallback
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            //.....
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

You have store the apex action calling in variable named **theContacts** whereas you are setting the parameter using **action.setParams** but actually it should be **theContacts.setParams**.
Same is the case for callback function. You should write it as **theContacts.setCallback** instead of **action.setCallback**

The correct piece of code is:-

```
createContact: function(component, contact) {
    var theContacts = component.get("c.saveContact");
    theContacts.setParams({
        "Contact": contact
    });
    theContacts.setCallback(this, function(response){
        //.....
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(theContacts);
}
```

Comment: Hello sanket kumar, thank you so much for your reply and assistance. I made the changes as you said so, but still receiving the same error, i just can't make the trick to get this working

Comment: @xianboga There is still a reference to the undefined variable `action` in `$A.enqueueAction(action);`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed for highlighting. I have corrected it now.

Comment: @xianboga, can you try now? I have corrected the code.